# Auth0 with Angular and Oidc-client

Tags: angular, auth0, oidc-client

I have created a new Angular application and I'm working on login with Auth0 but I encountered an issue with **oidc-client** by getting this error:

```
main.ts:12 TypeError: clientSettings.userStore is not a function
at new OidcService (ng-oidc-client.js:599)
```

In my **auth.module** I have this configuration:

```
NgOidcClientModule.forRoot({
      // prettier-ignore
      oidc_config: {
        authority: environment.sts.authority,
        client_id: environment.sts.clientId,
        redirect_uri: `${environment.appRoot}oidc-login-redirect-callback.html`,
        scope: 'openid profile',
        response_type: 'id_token token',
        post_logout_redirect_uri: `${environment.appRoot}/oidc-logout-redirect-callback.html`,
        silent_redirect_uri: `${environment.appRoot}/oidc-silent-renew-redirect-callback.html`,
        accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 10,
        automaticSilentRenew: true,
        metadata: {
          authorization_endpoint: `${environment.sts.authority}authorize audience=${environment.sts.audience}`,
          userinfo_endpoint: `${environment.sts.authority}userinfo`,
          issuer: environment.sts.authority,
          jwks_uri: `${environment.sts.authority}.well-known/jwks.json`,
          // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
          end_session_endpoint: `${environment.sts.authority}v2/logout?returnTo=${environment.appRootEncoded + 'oidc-logout-redirect-callback.html'}&client_id=${environment.sts.clientId}`
        },
        userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage })
      }
    })
```

and here is my **environment** file:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  appRoot: 'http://localhost:4200',
  appRootEncoded: 'http://localhost:4200',
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:4201',
  sts: {
    authority: 'https://dev-serj.eu.auth0.com/',
    clientId: 'R7fxgHNkPEj2VX1H7q4Fp0j2XnSqaudJ',
    audience: 'dev-serj-api'
  }
};
```

I'm more than sure there is a problem with **userStore** but I can't find a solution to fix it.

My oidc version:

```
"ng-oidc-client": "^1.0.7",
"oidc-client": "^1.10.1",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like version conflict between `ng-oidc-client` and `oidc-client`.

`ng-oidc-client` expects you to provide a function that returns `WebStorageStateStore`. However, the shape of `Config` comes directly from `oidc-client`, where it should be `WebStorageStateStore` and not a function.

Until quite recently, `userStore` field was declared as `any` in `oidc-client`, which allowed this trick. In 1.10 oidc-client was restructured, and the new typing is `userStore: WebStorageStateStore`.

A quick fix would be to provide a function - just as ng-oidc-client expects. And add a type assertion to suppress compile errors.

```
userStore: (() => new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage })) as any
```

And perhaps file a bug report for `ng-oidc-client`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Default config:

```
    userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({
      store: sessionStorage
    }),
```

So you can do this:

```
    userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({
      store: window.localStorage
    }),
```